# my singbox tun config doesnt work on ubuntu

Tags: networking, 22.10, 23.04

I use singbox and when I use tun mode, it creates a network interface, but the traffic of my system does not pass through it, I don't know why
And that I didn't have this problem with other distros, for example Manjaro was easily connected
This is the result of ifconfig:

```
tun0: flags=4305<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,NOARP,MULTICAST>  mtu 9000
    inet 172.19.0.1  netmask 255.255.255.252  destination 172.19.0.1
    inet6 fe80::28cc:a1dc:9317:fd12  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    unspec 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  txqueuelen 500  (UNSPEC)
    RX packets 38  bytes 3145 (3.1 KB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 40  bytes 3241 (3.2 KB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

I tried on ubuntu 23.04 and 22.10
Can someone help me to solve this?

Thanks